# Norm convergence of operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

If $(T_n)_n$ is a sequence of bounded operators from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\mapsto L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, and $T$ is an operator such that:

1-  $T_n$ converges to  $T$ pointwisely

2- $||{T_n-T}||_{L^2}\leq c,$    for some $c>0$.

Could this be enough to imply that   $T_n\rightarrow T$ in $L^2$-norm?

Comment: The answer is no. For example $T_nf(x)=f(x)$ for $\|x\|\le n$ and $T_nf(x)=0$ for $\|x\|> n.$ Then $T_n$ are projections and $\|T_n-T\|=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You should consider posting that as an answer rather than a comment so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.
Let $$(T_nf)(x)={\bf 1}_{\|u\|\le n}(x) f(x)$$
Then
$T_nf\to f$ for any $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3),$ since
$$\|T_nf-f\|_2^2=\int\limits_{\|x\|>n }|f(x)|^2\,dx\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
Therefore $T_n\to I$ pointwise. Moreover the formula implies $\|T_n-I\|\le 1.$
On the other hand $\|T_n-I\|\ge 1$ as for $f={\bf 1}_{n<\|x\|\le n+1}$ we have $(I-T_n)f=f.$

In general, if $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $T_n$ is a sequence of operators such that $T_nv\to Tv$ for every $v\in \mathcal{H},$ then by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem (uniform boundedness principle) the operators norms $\|T_n\|$ are uniformly bounded. Therefore the assumption $2.$ is redundant.
There exists a sequence of nontrivial orthogonal projections $P_n$ such that $P_n\to I$ pointwise and $\|I-P_n\|=1.$

Comment: +1. Another counter-example is $(T_nf)(x)=f(x)\cdot {\bf 1}_{[n,n+1]}(x),$ where $\|T_n\|$ converges point-wise to $T=0$ but $\|T_n-T\|=\|T_n\|=1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Your $T_n$ coincides with mine $T_{n+1}-T_n$.